# How do I customize the black border around JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

How do I customize the black border around the graphs in JQPlot?
I searched the CSS file extensively and couldn't find anything.

[UPDATE]

Please see this image if you are not understanding what i mean: 
http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5796/jqplot.png

Thanks

Comment: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php I see no black borders. Are you adding these in yourself?

Comment: I have added an image. http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5796/jqplot.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the jqplot options for grid [drawBorder](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Grid.drawBorder), [borderColor](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Grid.borderColor) and [shadow](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Grid.shadow):

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('container', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {grid:{borderColor:'transparent',shadow:false,drawBorder:false,shadowColor:'transparent'}});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('container', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {grid:{borderColor:'transparent',shadow:false,drawBorder:false}});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
      
<div id="container"></div>
```