# How can I remove a border of graph in jqplot?

Tags: graph, charts, jqplot

Does anyone know how to remove the border line of this Graph??
The graph is made with jqplot.
[image]

I mean the border line of box, outside one.

My code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('pieChart', [ all data to be drawn], 
        {   title: ' ', 
            seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false, 
                renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                rendererOptions: { padding: 2, sliceMargin: 2, showDataLabels: true } 
            },
            legend: { show:false, location: 'e' }
        }
    );
});
```

Please help me get rid of the borderline of box....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hints:

[How to remove border from jqplot charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375647/how-to-remove-border-from-jqplot-charts)

[How do I customize the black border around JQPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516393/how-do-i-customize-the-black-border-around-jqplot)

[jqplot, remove outside border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593051/jqplot-remove-outside-border)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jqplot-users/G60XBCAAajs

Comment: Thnx, The first link helped me out!